# How to convert string in to xml in android?

Tags: android, xml, xml-serialization

I am in need to convert data in List to XML string. Currently i am using the following method as conversion method in android,

```
  private String writeXml(List<DataItem> item)
   {

    XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    try {
        serializer.setOutput(writer);
        serializer.startDocument("UTF-16",null);
        serializer.startTag("", "MainData"); 
        serializer.startTag("", "Data"); 
        for (DataItem in: item)
            { 
            serializer.startTag("", "Key");
            serializer.text(in.getKey());
            serializer.endTag("", "Key");
            serializer.startTag("", "Value");
            serializer.text(in.getValue());
            serializer.endTag("", "Value");  
            }

        serializer.endTag("", "Data");
        serializer.endTag("", "MainData");
        serializer.endDocument();

        System.out.println(writer.toString());
        return writer.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I have seen this method in C#

```
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DataItem>));
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("","");
        serializer.Serialize(sw, tempdataitems,ns);

        form.AddField("EX" + i ,  sw.ToString());
```

But while trying this it shows

```
      Syntax error on token ">", Expression expected after this token
```

at the end of

```
      new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DataItem>));
```

Is it possible to have the same method in android? or
Is there any other method to do the same conversion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're item objects do not contain '>' character? if it does, you must escape this.